# Data Retention for External table in Snowflake using S3 Staging

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a external table in Snowflake using S3 Staging. I wants to know,what is the data retention period for the given table. I have referred Snowflake documentation but didn't able to find any answers.

Answer (score 1):

Time travel for external tables is not available, since the data lies in individual Storage Account and is not maintained by snowflake.